# Desktop Sharing Slow when no monitor is connected during boot

Tags: remote-desktop

This just started happening after a recent reboot of my 16.04 box.  It had been run running for about a month with reboots and everything with no problem.  I could use a windows box and VNC in and all was well.

I hadn't rebooted for about a month until this morning with no changes other than apt-get upgrades.  Now I when I connect it is very slow over VNC.

If I reboot while a monitor is plugged in, all is well.

None the less, I would like remote desktop to work when booted without a monitor attached (working meaning not painfully slow).

I'm not sure why it stopped working as I never had monitor on it after initial setup and has been just fine.  But one of those apt-get upgrades seem to have changed something.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just so folks know it looks like it had something to do with my AMD GPU.  The driver or something must have been updated or something and took effect during the reboot. I have sense taken the card out with no GPU and is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I am too observing this issue with Ubutnu 16.04.

**Preferred solution**:
 - Found out that the issue started coming in due to some package (yet to conclude which one, mostly update to display drivers) coming in with Ubuntu 16.04.2 and above.
 - With Ubuntu 16.0.1 issue is not seen. Even if you update --> upgrade from 16.04.1 to 16.04.{+} issue will not be seen.
 I have tried this and it is working fine.

**Solution 2**:
The workarounds (not solutions), I added dummy display to access same without issue.

Steps:
1. Insert a dummy video driver: sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
2. Since there's no default xorg.conf file that I could find anywhere, AND there are several locations where you can supposedly put it (/etc/X11, /usr/share/X11, ~) I created one and placed it in /etc/X11:

Code:

```
Section "Device"    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
    VideoRam 256000
EndSection


Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 5.0 - 1000.0
    VertRefresh 5.0 - 200.0
    ModeLine "1920x1080" 148.50 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +Hsync +Vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/791757)

Comment: Made the changes @J.Starnes

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04.7, xserver-xorg-video-dummy fails to install ("unmet dependencies").
Installing xserver-xorg-video-dummy-lts-xenial worked.